# Which component cannot handle the higher wattage?

Tags: led, watts

First time posting a question, so hopefully I've stated all the required details.

As the title is not very specific, here is an explanation of my project. I'm making a revised version of the magnetic table lamp, as shown here:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Magnetic-table-lamp/

The electronics inside are shown in the schematic below. I use a W10M bridge rectifier (1.5A, 50-1000V), a CD263 capacitor (100V), 39ohm/1W resistors, 12V power supply and a LED 3V,0.15A.
[image: magnetic table lamp schematic]

Now here's my question: I messed up a bit with the construction of the cubes, which resulted in a high resistance and thus high voltage drop in between my cubes. I tried to fix this by switching to a 24V power supply, and 120ohm/3W resistors (a bit power-heavy, but a lower influence of the resistance between cubes).  However, things get smelly and I think a component is not suited for this voltage. Can anybody pinpoint what causes the problem?

Comment: Don't try to brute-force something that doesn't work.  You can start a fire that way.  Take it back apart, figure out what you did wrong, fix that (and any other parts that you may have fried while failing to burn your house down), and run it as designed.

Comment: Could be part of it, but the 39 Ohms is already bordering on the limit/rating of the LEDs, and if the resistor is low tolerance it's possible you are slowly killing/overheating the LEDs. Also, the resistor itself is getting close to it's own Wattage rating, so again, poor thermal or low tolerance issues will eventually make strange smells and explosions

Comment: Ahh, is that a 12V DC or AC supply?  (Or is the bridge rectifier put on the front end to stop reverse poalrity issues?)

Comment: @AaronD: You are right. Unfortunately I can't change the inter-cube connections anymore, but I'll revert to the old resistor values.

Comment: @KyranF: Thanks for your advice. To be sure, I'll switch to 47 Ohms.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold: It is a DC supply. The bridge rectifier is added, because the design of the cubes implies that for each cube, you cannot identify the + and - lines from each other. The bridge rectifier solves this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate how much power each component is dissipating, and compare that to its rating.

$$Watts = Volts \times  Amps$$

Assuming you are using an AC supply, the output of the rectifier should be about 24V (it could be over 30V if your capacitor is large enough to hold the peak voltage). Two 3V LEDs in series drop 7V, leaving 17V across the 120Ω resistor. We can calculate the current through the resistor using Ohms Law:

$$I = \frac{V}{R} = \frac{17V}{120 \Omega} = 0.142A$$

Now calculate the power in the resistor:

$$17V \times  0.142A = 2.4W$$

How hot will a 3W resistor get when dissipating 2.4W? If it is a metal oxide or wirewound type then it's probably rated for a temperature rise of ~200°C at 3W. Therefore at 2.4W it will rise to about \$\dfrac{2.4}{3} \times 200 = 160 ^{\circ} C\$ above ambient. That is why things are getting smelly - the resistors *may* be able to handle the power, but they are getting very hot doing so.

Comment: Thanks Bruce for your answer. You are absolutely correct. I didn't know this about resistors, I just assumed it worked as correct because the resistors are able to handle the power. Did not gave it much thought about the temperature rise though. I'll change the design.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your supply delivers \$24\$VDC it should work.

$$I=\frac{24-2-2 \times 3}{120} = \frac{16}{120} = 133\text{mA}$$ and $$P_{\text{res}}= 16\text{V}\times 0.133\text{A} = 2.13\text{W}$$

But if you are using \$24\$VAC, then \$I=217\$mA and \$P_{\text{res}}=5.6\$W. This could be the problem.

Assuming \$24\$VDC you could consider using \$4\$ LED's in one string and a \$1\%\$ \$3\$W \$82\Omega\$ resistor in series. That would preserve a lot of energy otherwise wasted as heat (\$I=121\$mA, \$P_{\text{res}}=1.2\$W).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It considers a VDC supply.
It is a good suggestion that I could place the 4 LEDs in series, would be more energy-sufficient indeed. I've read something on the forum of the Magnetic Table Lamp-instructable, that he chose to make two LED lines, to safeguard against broken LEDs? Anyway, I'm more than happy to consider your option.